# Passing a View Model within a URL.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, viewmodel

I'm trying to pass a view model to my controller.

```
 @if (User.IsInRole("Customer"))
            {

                <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="Rent Car" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("PassingCar", "Bookings", new { id = item.VehicleID, Model = Model.Booking })'" />

            }
```

I'm using a dynamic model so I can use both Vehicle and Booking in this view.

When the code gets to my controller the ID has been passed over but the data in the ViewModel is gone.

```
 public ActionResult PassingCar( int id, CreateBookingViewModel createdModel)
        {
            ///Checks that Vehicle exists in DB and v property is not null
            if (v == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            else
            {


                /// sets the Vehicle attribute of the BookingViewModel to vehicle passed over
                createdModel.Vehicle = v;

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Bookings");
        }
```

If anybody has an idea what i'm doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discoverer my problem so I'm gonna post an answer for anyone encountering the same thing, and find this thread.

Because both of the names in the URL Action where called Model, this would create a brand new ViewModel passed to the view. This was due to the fact in my View, the model was a dynamic model I created so the Object that was being created was anew ExpandoObject.

A solution would of been to cast the ExpandoObject to the correct type, but I discovered a different way to solve my specific problem just using TempData. Either way would of worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the text of the URL you end up at?

But at a guess, you might want to replace Model = Model.Booking with Model = JSON.Encode(Model.Booking)

Oh.  And another probability.  You name the parameter "Model" in the Url Action, but "createdModel" in the method signature.

Comment: So The Url of the page before I click the button has the start date and finish date contained within it, which is what I want. http://localhost:52574/Vehicles/VehiclesView?BookingID=0&BookingDate=01%2F01%2F0001%2000%3A00%3A00&StartDate=05%2F22%2F2019%2000%3A00%3A00&FinishDate=05%2F25%2F2019%2000%3A00%3A00&isActive=False&Price=0

Comment: @MarkMcAllister Do you have the URL for after you click the button?  I'd expect it to include /Bookings/PassingCar or similar.

Comment: http://localhost:52574/Bookings/Create   Just the standard name of the Views,nothing seems to be carrying over.

Comment: @MarkMcAllister Ah, that's the end step, and we're trying to get the in between one.  I suspect the edit to my answer is the reason.  "Model" in the URL, but "createdModel" in the method parameters.

Comment: So for some reason if I change the name to createdModel on the URL Action the model that gets passed through is null. Same goes ViceVersa.

Comment: @MarkMcAllister Just remembered, even with the redirect, you should be able to get the "PassingCar" URL from the browser DevTools on the Network tab.

Comment: Figured out the problem. Thanks for your help. I'll post an answer in case anyone is googling for the same problem.